# "Unable to use key file "...\id_rsa" (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key)" when authenticating with PuTTY

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, ssh-keys, password-less

I have setup custom SSH keys on target Linux `host2`.

I'm  able to passwordless ssh from Linux `host1` to `host2` using the below command.

```
ssh -i /app/misc/myssh_keys/my_id_rsa myuser@host2
```

I then copy the `/app/misc/myssh_keys/my_id_rsa` to my Windows location `C:\putty\my_id_rsa`

I then try to connect from Windows to Linux `host2`, but it prompts me for the password instead of passwordless login.

Below is my command:

```
C:\putty\putty.exe -ssh -i C:\putty\my_id_rsa myuser@host2
```

I'm getting the following output with the password prompt:

```
Unable to use key file "C:\putty\my_id_rsa" (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key)
Using username "myuser".
myhost@host2's password:
```

Below is the system details for Linux `host2`

```
uname -a
Linux host2 3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 16 14:19:51 EDT 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Below is the system details for Windows host

```
C:\Users>systeminfo

Host Name:                 mywinhost
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Member Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          hp
Registered Organization:   Hewlett-Packard Company
Product ID:                00321-OEM-8552671-07008
Original Install Date:     01-04-2017, 13:05:14
System Boot Time:          15-12-2019, 14:00:52
System Manufacturer:       HP
System Model:              HP 280 G2 MT (Legacy)
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel ~3700 Mhz
BIOS Version:              AMI A0.25, 06-02-2017
```

I read somewhere on Stack Overflow that I may have to convert the `C:\putty\my_id_rsa` key using PuTTYgen, but I would appreciate the exact commands and all the steps I would need to perform to get the ssh working.

Any other solution would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

PuTTY cannot use keys in OpenSSH format.

You need to convert your key to .ppk format first. For that, use [PuTTYgen](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey-puttygen) from PuTTY package.

- Run PuTTYgen;
- Press *Load* to load the private key in OpenSSH format;
- Press *Save private key* to save the private key in `.ppk` format